# What does "s'agir" mean?

Tags: vocabulaire

I ran across this while reading, and none of the definitions I found [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/s%27agir) fit the bill. I get the gist of the sentence because I've read this in English, but I still can't make sense of the word itself in this context.

> Il s'agissait en effet de Drago Malefoy.

Comment: With this verb, it is important to know what was going on in the previous sentence. For example: No one knew who had stolen the note. Everyone searched for it high and low. But it was indeed Draco Malefoy who had done it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The link you provided](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/s%27agir) does give the answer to that question:

> il s'agit de (=c'est) - it's a matter of, it's
> (=c'est à propos de) it's about
> Il s'agit d'une intervention bénigne. - It's a minor operation.
> de quoi s'agit-il? - What is it about?

So, there you have a translation, a proper question and an example.

[Un francophone](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3021/1246) also provided *il est question de* and that can be also said in English: *it's a question of*.

Another example

> Il s'agit d'une pièce à deux personnages. - It's a play with two people.

With own words: You can use that phrase when you want to specify the object you're talking about more precisely. For instance: *It's an animal with eight feet.*

Thus, your sentence could be translate:

> It's indeed Drago Malefoy.
>
> Admittedly, it's Drago Malefoy.

---

Said that, I wouldn't use *a question of* or *a matter of* in your example. Both could be used in the second meaning that *Un francophone* said, for instance:

> *It's a matter of life and death.*
>
> *It's still a matter of debate.*

or in phrases like

> It's simply a question of time. (C'est juste une question de temps)

Comment: Il s'agissait de: It was indeed Draco Malfoy. Il s'agit de refers back to something earlier in a text; often, to translate it, one needs to know what was going on.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to propose another translation of the expression, maybe more generic than the others. I think that in most cases, *il s'agit* can be translated by the expression *it happens to be*.

For example:

> Il s'agissait en effet de Drago Malefoy.

Could be translated by:

> It indeed happened to be Drago Malefoy.

It's not really a pretty translation, but it's somehow easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit ici de l'emploi pronominal impersonnel d'[agir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agir) (en C)

- *il s'agit de + nom ou inf.* signifie *il est question de* (*it's about*).
- *il s'agit de + inf.* signifie *il est important de* (*it is important to*).

Dans ton cas, *il est question en effet de Drago Malefoy*.

Comment: That seems like a really good answer except for one problem-- I don't know the expression "Il est question de" either, and all the internet translations say it means "Il s'agit de," which is unfortunately not helpful here, haha.

Comment: @Aerovistae added translation in english.

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously my mind came up with

It deals with, 
It concerns,

But for direct simplicity, "it's about" takes the biscuit!  i.e. gets my vote! ( dunk, dunk, slam dunk! n'est Pas?) [image]

Comment: i don't know what to make of that picture